# 301 Redirect URL Appending Query String

Tags: php, redirects, apache, rewrite, .htaccess

From yesterday, I'm trying this 301 url redirect but its not working as expected. Please help me with this. here is the .htaccess file code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
rewriterule ^deals/(.*)$ details.php?id=$1 [L]
rewritecond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} publisher.php

Redirect 301 /deals/74/product-name.html http://mydomain.com/74/product-name.html
```

Whenever I enter www.mydomain.com/deals/74/product-name.html, It redirects me to "www.mydomain.com/deals/74/product-name.html?id=74&name=product-name"

I'm not sure why its appending "?id=74&name=product-name" after url? I want to display only "www.mydomain.com/deals/74/product-name.html"

I don't know how to fix this problem. I'll appreciate if you can guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Append "?id=74&name=product-name" is what the line 6 of your code does:

```
rewriterule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ product.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```